# PySpark: Iterate over list of dataframes

Tags: python, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a couple of dataframe and I want all columns of them to be in uppercase.
I did this as follows:

```
for col in df1.columns:
    df1 = df1.withColumnRenamed(col, col.upper())

for col in df2.columns:
    df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed(col, col.upper())
```

No I want to do this in an array iteration like this:

```
list = (df1, df2, df3)
for x in list:
   for col in x.columns:
      x = x.withColumnRenamed(col, col.upper())
```

But somehow this does not work (but no error displayed), the columns stay in lowercase. I also tried to attach an "return x" at the end but that doesn't work either. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay pri's answer worked for me if I added a `global` statement to it.

```
global df1, df2, df3
a = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
for x in a:
    for col in globals()[x].columns:
        globals()[x] = globals()[x].withColumnRenamed(col, col.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

The changes to your dataframe are not reflecting in the original variables viz. `df1`, `df2`, and `df3`.

You could use the `globals()` function to achieve this. Code below:

```
a = ['df1', 'df2', 'df3']
for x in a:
    for col in globals()[x].columns:
        globals()[x] = globals()[x].withColumnRenamed(col, col.upper())
```

You might have to use either `globals()` or `locals()` depending on your use case.

`globals()` and `locals()` both help in accessing a variable by a string, and both of them return a dictionary of variables. You can read more about them online.

EDIT : Also, list is a keyword in your code, you should change the variable name to something else.

Comment: Hi Pri, thanks for your reply. However, the proposal does not seem to work, both ```globals()``` and ```locals()``` ... ```globals()``` gives me a ```KeyError: 'df1'```, ```locals()``` does not give me an error but has no effect.

Comment: @Niels Did you mention the dataframes in quotes in your list?

Comment: Also, list is a keyword in python. I've edited my answer to explain that.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in quotes, don't know whats going wrong. Is globals maybe a function I have to import first?

Comment: Could you share the code you're trying? I tried it and it seemed to work fine for me.

Comment: I tried exactly your code. But I also asked a colleague and he tried it with Pandas and it worked. So I think it has to do with Spark... You tried it on PySpark/Spark?

Comment: @Niels Yes I tried it on PySpark (Spark 2.3)

Comment: Hmm could it be a version problem? My organization is using Spark 1.6.0

Comment: What is the Python version you're using?

Comment: I'm using Version Python 2.7.11

Comment: I tried with Spark 2 and Python 2.7, it worked fine for me :)

Comment: Or do I have to set something to global before? Maybe the dataframes I am using or the column dictionary?